# drawing a regular polygon over an image and calculate the area 

Tags: matlab, polygon

I want to draw a regular polygon over an image in matlab and then calculate the area of that polygon.

Answer (score 0):

have you try area or polyarea?

Comment: I have used roipoly to draw a polygon over the image, but i can't draw regularly shape polygon with that. so first, I need to draw a regular polygon on the image. whats ur suggestion for that

Comment: You can try to make a "normal" point which the another polygon's vertex will be calculated by that point. For example, if you want to make equilateral triangle polygon over the image, you can just digitizing a single point of the triangle using roipoly. The rest points coordinate can be calculated manually.

Comment: If the polygon you want to make aren't in same size (and/or orientation), you can add the "normal" point to be two or more. For example, if you want to make circles with different diameter, you can digitize two points which are the diameter of circle, then you can calculate the rest points manually by using that two points.